# In Git,how to get the entire contents of a different branch to the branch i want to work in?

Tags: git

Let's say I'm in Branch A. There is other Branch B which has my entire project files. I want to get all the files in Branch B to Branch A so that I can work on errors in the project by being in Branch A and push accordingly.

Edit:

I'm Sorry if I didn't explain it perfectly. So my situation is, There is a branch called s1 which my friend works on. I have a branch v1 which I work on. Now I'm feeling like the content in my branch is complete crap, So I want the entire content of branch s1 in my branch v1 and also the files in branch v1 in my local repository. I did "git push origin s1:v1", but when I do "git checkout v1" I could still see the previous files of v1 only. Help me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you just start in branch B and `git checkout -b branch-a`?

Comment: Merge? Rebase?.

Comment: I'm Sorry if I didn't explain it perfectly. So my situation is, There is a branch called s1 which my friend works on. I have a branch v1 which I work on. Now I'm feeling like the content in my branch is complete crap, So I want the entire content of branch s1 in my branch v1 and also the files in branch v1 in my local repository. I did "git push origin s1:v1", but when I do "git checkout v1" I could still see the previous files of v1 only.Help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: First your friend need to push to remote repo. Then you need to pull it(v1l. Then the best option(if you want to scrap your files) is to simply delete your branch and then checkout new branch from v1

Comment: If you want to work in your friend's branch, just `checkout` that branch. You can delete your own if you hate it. If you want your own fork of your friend's branch, check it out first and then `checkout -b v2` and work in v2. Don't try and do tricky things rewriting the remote copy of your branch, it isn't worth it and branches are free. Just get a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming s1 is pushed remotely, first sync your local:

```
git fetch origin
```

Now checkout s1 locally:

```
git checkout s1
```

Checkout your v1 branch

```
git checkout v1
```

Use the s1 branch to rebase v1:

```
git rebase s1
```

If you have been modifying files that s1 also has modified, you will likely have merge conflicts that you will have to iterate through.  At the end, you will have effectively the s1 branch plus your v1 changes that were not conflicts with the s1 changes.  If you want to unilaterally take the changes on s1, you can do:

```
git rebase -s ours s1
```

Yes `ours` seems confusing but a rebase is the opposite of a merge in terms of what is the base branch, so to take the changes from `s1`, you must use `ours`.